# Is the structure "Making ... into ..." correct?

Tags: sentence-construction

Is this sentence structure correct and usable:

> Making ... into ...

Or must I use the word `converting` rather than `making`?

An example could be:

> Making sunlight into electricity is an easy task for a solar cell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Converting sunlight into electricity is an easy task for a solar cell** is most commonly used since solar panels convert the sun's rays into electricity by exciting electrons in silicon cells using the photons of light from the sun.

- The verb *convert*  means to change in form, function or shape. The verb *make* means to cause, exist, or bring out.
  Also, you can use the verb *turn*: **Turning sunlight into electricity is an easy task for a solar cell**

Comment: So, to summarize, please correct me in this: I can say "*Making electricity **from** sunlight is...*" similarly to saying "*Creating electricity **from** sunlight is...*" but not "*Making sunlight **into** electricity is...*", which should rather be "*Converting sunlight **into** electricity is...*" or "*Turning sunlight **into** electricity is...*"?

Comment: For me, the last one *converting... into* is more common used than *turning..into*. I read so many articles about how to produce electricity by solar cells and most of them use  *Converting.... into*. The second one which is about *making or creating * I have no idea about that. It may depend on the context.